# What date for resignation?

Tags: resignation

I work for a school district (office staff), my last duty day for the school year was June 9th.  We received notice this morning that we have to move (my husband is military and has to report to a new duty station within the next 2 months). In writing my resignation letter do I give my resignation as effective immediately? Or provide a two weeks notice even though I'm technically already out for the summer? I can provide the two weeks, that's not a problem, just odd to me since I am not expected to be in the office until late July. I plan on going in to the school to see my principal on Monday.

Comment: you might get better, more focused answers if you provide the details about your location / country.

Comment: Do you have any work you'd need to turn over/knowledge you'd have to transfer or is it simply a matter of them finding a replacement?

Comment: Do you have a contract with your employer? Are you being paid from now until late July? If the answer to both questions is "no", then I don't see what difference it makes either way: they're not paying you, and you're not working. If you have 2 months to report, maybe you stay and go to work in July anyway?

Comment: Perhaps you should, you know, ask the principal that when you go in.

Comment: @mxyzplk-SEstopbeingevil, but isn't the risk that the principal fires her effective immediately, and only gives her two weeks of salary instead of two months?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk That's assuming OP is even being paid during the break, which would also depend on location.

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of laws and regulations.

If it is not explicitly forbidden, then you can provide the two weeks notice while in vacation.

---

At my previous job, the law allowed the notice to overlap with the vacation. However, the company had a rule that the notice counts only working days, not vacations. It could mean that you handed the notice during vacation, but it actually started to count down only after the return to work.